# Reading data from firebase database to a custom listView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I am trying to read data that I inserted into firebase database, I want to display the data in custom listView. I am using this method but it seems that I am missing something.
I can't insert data into my arraylist.
**UPDATED** I inserted the values and now it gives me

> attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference
>   on my get methods

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        PatientInformation patientInfo = new PatientInformation();
        patientInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class).getName());
        patientInfo.setAge(ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class).getAge());
        patientInfo.setDate(ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class).getDate());
        ArrayList<PatientInformation> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(patientInfo);
        PatientInformationAdapter pAdapter = new PatientInformationAdapter(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: We're missing some information here that is needed to be able to help you. We'll need to see what node you attach the listener to, essentially what happens before you call `showData`. We'll also want to see the JSON at the location you listen to, as text (no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

Your arrayList is of type PatientInformation so I think you could just add patientInfo which is of type PatientInformation also.

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    PatientInformation patientInfo = new PatientInformation();
    patientInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class).getName());
    patientInfo.setAge(ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class).getAge());
    patientInfo.setDate(ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class).getDate());
    ArrayList<PatientInformation> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(patientInfo);

    PatientInformationAdapter pAdapter = new PatientInformationAdapter(this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Is the userID valid? Because if not it may produce a null PatientInformation object. Check it cause it might be a problem

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new array list and adapter for every child node of the results. You probably want to create only one array list and adapter, like this:

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<PatientInformation> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        PatientInformation patientInfo = ds.child(userID).getValue(PatientInformation.class)
        arrayList.add(patientInfo);
    }
    PatientInformationAdapter pAdapter = new PatientInformationAdapter(this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
}
```